# Yeti Microphone Experiencing Static When Close to My MacBook Air: How to Fix?

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, microphone, recording, macbook-air

A month and a half ago I purchased a Yeti microphone. It works great, but from the start, I noticed an annoying issue: any time my computer was close to the microphone, there would be an annoying static noise, which came through on the recording.

Eventually, I narrowed it down to having something to do with the wifi signal. When I shut off wifi on my MacBook Air, the static totally went away. When I re-enabled wifi, there was an immediate flare-up of static. I repeated this several times to confirm.

I noticed something else: as weird as it sounds, it only happened when the microphone was near the left side of the computer. On the opposite side, no static. I don't know if the wifi chip is on the left side or what, but it's what I noticed.

Unfortunately my setup is such that in order to have easy access to the computer, I needed it on the right side of the microphone, which caused the static.

My solution so far has been to place my computer on the opposite side, but inaccessible to me. I use a bluetooth keyboard to still be able to interact with the computer as necessary. All static has ceased with this setup, but… it is rather annoying to have to do this each time I want to record.

I'm hoping I can find some workaround so I can have my computer in a place that is most convenient, without causing that static again.

I've done a lot of searching, but have as of yet been unable to find any solution. So, I'm hoping someone here can help.

Comment: Change the channel on the access point so the interference is dampened

Comment: Not much of a surprise there. Maybe you can switch from 2.4 GHz to 5 GHz WiFi or the other way round. Also, b/g/n transmission may make a difference -- in other words, a different access point _may_ help; potentially also making your notobook believe it needs less transmission power (closer to access point). _But_ you need to try that. Other than that, the induced audible impact decreases exponentially with the distance from you notebook's antenna.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this happens. Pre-amps can pick up 2.4GHz in error. I've experienced it with outputs on an external DAC. Wireless traffic sounds like little "popping" noises.

The two pragmatic solutions would be:

1. Switch your Wi-Fi network to 5GHz (If supported). Mic shouldn't pick this up.
2. Build an RF shield to inhibit its transmission towards the mic. Tin(UK)/Aluminum(US) foil should be sufficient to bring levels down to where it's inaudible.